# Can I use ansible-playbook "--extra-vars" to execute roles conditionally

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, configuration-management

I have an Ansible playbook I am working on and I am trying to make the execution a little more dynamic. I have two roles that don't always need to be run in conjunction, sometimes only one of them needs to be run. I have been digging into the Ansible docs, and I am wondering if I can pass `--extra-vars` parameters to only run a specific role.

Currently, my playbook looks like this:

```
---
- hosts: default
  become: true

  roles:
      - role: upgrades
        when: {{ upgrades_role }}

      - role: custom-packages 
        when: {{ custom_packages_role }}
```

So, the goal is to be able to run:

```
ansible-playbook playbook.yml -e "upgrades_role=upgrades"
```

And this would *only* run the `upgrades` role and *skip* the `custom_packages` role.

Similarly, if I want to run *both* roles on the same hosts/system:

```
ansible-playbook playbook.yml -e "upgrades_role=upgrades custom_packages_role=custom-packages"
```

This would run *both* roles.

Based on my understating of Ansible syntax and the `--extra-vars, -e` parameter, this seems like it should work. I just want to be sure I am doing this the proper way and avoiding anti-patterns.

**Ansible Version:** `2.14`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most common way will be to use `tags`; updating the  example in the question:

```yaml
---
- hosts: default
  become: true

  roles:
      - role: upgrades
        tags: upgrades

      - role: custom-packages 
        tags: packages
...
```

So, the goal is to be able to run:

```bash
# Execute all the roles
ansible-playbook playbook.yml

# Execute only the upgrade
ansible-playbook playbook.yml -t upgrades

# Execute only the setup of custom packages
ansible-playbook playbook.yml -t packages
```

Here is the documentation for [tags](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_tags.html).

Using variables and `when` is possible, but you'll need to ensure to cast it to `bool`.

Comment: Like so? -> `ansible-playbook playbook.yml -e "upgrades_role=true custom_packages_role=true"`

Comment: please avoid the use of variables for this, if you're starting using Ansible, it will be better for you that you avoid antipatterns.

Comment: Using the variables will make the playbook more complicated than it requires, you will need to have defaults declared or define all the variables in all your conditionals to prevent the error `The conditional check '{{ upgrades_role }}' failed. The error was: error while evaluating conditional ({{ upgrades_role }}): 'upgrades_role' is undefined\n\nThe error appears to be in 'playbook.yaml'`.

Answer (score 2):

Let me provide you with a framework to automate the use case that you described:

**Pass --extra-vars parameters to only run a specific role**

Create the project

```bash
shell> ls -1
ansible.cfg
hosts
playbook.yml.j2
roles
setup.yml
```

```ini
shell> cat ansible.cfg 
[defaults]
gathering = explicit
collections_path = $HOME/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/
inventory = $PWD/hosts
roles_path = $PWD/roles
retry_files_enabled = false
stdout_callback = yaml
```

```ini
shell> cat hosts 
localhost
```

The playbook *setup.yml*

- Gets the list of the roles. Fit the variable *my_roles_dir* to your needs.
- Creates file *my_roles_order.yml* with the list *my_roles_order*. The purpose of this file is to create the order of the roles.
- Creates file *my_roles_enable.yml* with the dictionary *my_roles_enable*. The purpose of this file is to create defaults.
- Creates file *playbook.yml* from the template. Fit the template to your needs.

```yaml
shell> cat setup.yml 
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    my_roles_dir: "{{ lookup('config', 'DEFAULT_ROLES_PATH') }}"

  tasks:

    - set_fact:
        my_roles: "{{ my_roles|default([]) +
                      lookup('pipe', 'ls -1 ' ~ item).splitlines() }}"
      loop: "{{ my_roles_dir }}"

    - copy:
        dest: "{{ playbook_dir }}/my_roles_order.yml"
        content: |
          my_roles_order:
          {{ my_roles|to_nice_yaml|indent(2, true) }}
        force: "{{ my_roles_order_force|default(false) }}"
    - include_vars: my_roles_order.yml

    - copy:
        dest: "{{ playbook_dir }}/my_roles_enable.yml"
        content: |
          my_roles_enable:
          {% for role in my_roles %}
            {{ role }}: false
          {% endfor %}
        force: "{{ my_roles_enable_force|default(false) }}"
    - include_vars: my_roles_enable.yml

    - template:
        src: playbook.yml.j2
        dest: "{{ playbook_dir }}/playbook.yml"
```

```yaml
shell> cat playbook.yml.j2
- hosts: localhost
  become: true

  vars_files:
    - my_roles_enable.yml

  roles:
{% for role in my_roles_order %}
    - role: {{ role }}
      when: {{ role }}_role|default(my_roles_enable.{{ role }})|bool
{% endfor %}
```

Test the trivial roles

```bash
shell> tree roles/
roles/
├── current_packages
│   └── tasks
│       └── main.yml
├── custom_packages
│   └── tasks
│       └── main.yml
├── stable_packages
│   └── tasks
│       └── main.yml
└── upgrades
    └── tasks
        └── main.yml

8 directories, 4 files
```

```yaml
shell> cat roles/*/tasks/main.yml
- debug:
    msg: Role current_packages running ...
- debug:
    msg: Role custom_packages running ...
- debug:
    msg: Role stable_packages running ...
- debug:
    msg: Role upgrades running ...
```

Run the playbook *setup.yml*

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook setup.yml

PLAY [localhost] ****************************************************************************************

TASK [set_fact] *****************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=/scratch/tmp7/test-204/roles)

TASK [copy] *********************************************************************************************
changed: [localhost]

TASK [include_vars] *************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [copy] *********************************************************************************************
changed: [localhost]

TASK [include_vars] *************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [template] *****************************************************************************************
changed: [localhost]

PLAY RECAP **********************************************************************************************
localhost: ok=6    changed=3    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

---

This creates *playbook.yml*

```yaml
shell> cat playbook.yml
- hosts: localhost
  become: true

  vars_files:
    - my_roles_enable.yml

  roles:
    - role: current_packages
      when: current_packages_role|default(my_roles_enable.current_packages)|bool
    - role: custom_packages
      when: custom_packages_role|default(my_roles_enable.custom_packages)|bool
    - role: stable_packages
      when: stable_packages_role|default(my_roles_enable.stable_packages)|bool
    - role: upgrades
      when: upgrades_role|default(my_roles_enable.upgrades)|bool
```

and the files

```yaml
shell> cat my_roles_order.yml
my_roles_order:
  - current_packages
  - custom_packages
  - stable_packages
  - upgrades
```

```yaml
shell> cat my_roles_enable.yml
my_roles_enable:
  current_packages: false
  custom_packages: false
  stable_packages: false
  upgrades: false
```

By default, the playbook runs nothing. Here you can *"pass --extra-vars parameters to only run a specific role"*. For example, enable the role *upgrades*

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook playbook.yml -e upgrades_role=true

PLAY [localhost] *****************************************************************************

TASK [current_packages : debug] **************************************************************
skipping: [localhost]

TASK [custom_packages : debug] ***************************************************************
skipping: [localhost]

TASK [stable_packages : debug] ***************************************************************
skipping: [localhost]

TASK [upgrades : debug] **********************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg: Role upgrades running ...

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************
localhost: ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=3    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

---

If you want to change the order and/or the enablement defaults of the roles edit the files *my_roles_order.yml* and *my_roles_enable.yml*. For example, put the role *upgrades* in the first place and enable it by default

```yaml
shell> cat my_roles_order.yml
my_roles_order:
  - upgrades
  - current_packages
  - custom_packages
  - stable_packages
```

```yaml
shell> cat my_roles_enable.yml
my_roles_enable:
  current_packages: false
  custom_packages: false
  stable_packages: false
  upgrades: true
```

---

Update the playbook

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook setup.yml
```

Test it

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook playbook.yml

PLAY [localhost] *****************************************************************************

TASK [upgrades : debug] **********************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg: Role upgrades running ...

TASK [current_packages : debug] **************************************************************
skipping: [localhost]

TASK [custom_packages : debug] ***************************************************************
skipping: [localhost]

TASK [stable_packages : debug] ***************************************************************
skipping: [localhost]

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************
localhost: ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=3    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

---

It's practical to create a file if you want to enable/disable multiple roles on the command line. For example,

```yaml
shell> cat myroles.yml 
upgrades_role: false
stable_packages_role: true
custom_packages_role: true
```

Use it in the command line

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook playbook.yml -e @myroles.yml

PLAY [localhost] *****************************************************************************

TASK [upgrades : debug] **********************************************************************
skipping: [localhost]

TASK [current_packages : debug] **************************************************************
skipping: [localhost]

TASK [custom_packages : debug] ***************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg: Role custom_packages running ...

TASK [stable_packages : debug] ***************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg: Role stable_packages running ...

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************
localhost: ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=2    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

---

Don't display skipped hosts

```yaml
shell> ANSIBLE_DISPLAY_SKIPPED_HOSTS=false ansible-playbook playbook.yml -e @myroles.yml

PLAY [localhost] *****************************************************************************

TASK [custom_packages : debug] ***************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg: Role custom_packages running ...

TASK [stable_packages : debug] ***************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg: Role stable_packages running ...

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************
localhost: ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=2    rescued=0    ignored=0
```